# Are these threads in htop using any resources?

Tags: process, ffmpeg, htop

[image: screenshot of htop, some threads in green text some in white]

My node application spawns ffmpeg processes. In htop, there are a bunch of ffmpeg processes I would have expected to have ended but they are still shown in htop. The threads in green are the process that is currently active.

The ones in white are shown using memory, and the time column is not incrementing. Are these processes using any resources and should I be looking into what's causing these processes to now close cleanly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they're using resources, though its hard to say how much; could be a very small amount.

First thing to check for is just with `ps`, see if their status is `Z` (zombie). Which would mean they've exited, but you're not calling `wait`/`waitpid`/etc. on them. (Probably not, as I think Node handles this for you).

Otherwise, they've probably got some RAM, some number of file descriptors (likely in both ffmpeg and Node), and of course a process in use; you will run out of all of those if your app is long-running and keeps leaking them. I suppose worst would be if it still has that HTTP connection open; that will consume resources on dar.fm too. Tools like `ps`, `lsof`, and even `strace` can help check on what resources those ffmpegs are using.

Whether you should fix it... is something you'll have to decide based on how much it costs in programmer time to fix vs. extra hardware/operations time to manage.

Comment: Adding to this that irrespective of the status, each entry in the process table adds overhead on a O(Log(N)) scheduler... OK! As you rightly wrote : a very small amount ;-)